# Saving AWS Environment Variables to File - How to handle special character '&'

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I am trying to run a django `manage.py` task via cron, on AWS Elasticbeanstalk (EB).

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/notification_cron.sh > /dev/null
```

The `notification_cron.sh` script calls a django `manage.py` task.

Django needs EB's environment variables (like RDS_PORT, RDS_DB_NAME, RDS_PASSWORD etc). So I am saving these environment variables into a file at deployment, and reloading those in the bash script that also calls the manage.py task.

This is part of my deployment config in `.ebextensions`:

```
commands:
  001_envvars_to_bash_source_file:
    command: |
      # source our elastic beanstalk environment variables
      /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment|perl -ne "/^\w/ or next; s/: /=/; print qq|\$_|" > /usr/local/bin/envvars
      chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/envvars

files:
  "/usr/local/bin/notification_cron.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/ec2-user/.aws/config"
      set -o allexport
      # Loading environment data
      source /usr/local/bin/envvars
      set +o allexport
      cd /opt/python/current/app/
      source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
      python manage.py my_management_task
```

The problem is caused by the line

```
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment|perl -ne "/^\w/ or next; s/: /=/; print qq|\$_|" > /usr/local/bin/envvars
```

or the alternate sed equivalent

```
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output yaml | sed -n '1!p' | sed -e 's/^\(.*\): /\1=/g' > /usr/local/bin/envvars
```

The contents of `/usr/local/bin/envvars` are not always in quotes:

```
PYTHONPATH="/opt/python/current/app/mydjangoapp:$PYTHONPATH"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mydjangoapp.settings
AWS_ACTIVE='true'
RDS_PORT='5432'
RDS_HOSTNAME=hostname.host.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
RDS_USERNAME=master
RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
RDS_PASSWORD=My&Password
```

This causes trouble where an environment variable has the "&" character.

```
'RDS_PASSWORD': My&Password
```

Bash splits this up at the "&" character when I `source /usr/local/bin/envvars` to import them back into my script before calling django's manage.py.

**Phew. My question is:**

How do I get `RDS_PASSWORD="My&Password"` in the `/usr/local/bin/envvars` file (note the double quotes required) without breaking the other lines like `RDS_PORT='5432'`?

Comment: Why not just double-quote all your variables in the file?

Comment: That envvars file is created by me automatically during deployment using AWS' get-config (which dumps the environment variables in YAML), replacing : with =, and piping it to a file. It double quotes the PYTHONPATH, single-quotes RDS_PORT and doesn't quote RDS_PASSWORD at all. How do I double-quote all or just the RDS_PASSWORD value there while not re-double-quoting the variables already in quotes?

Comment: The reason why I asked this, how do you expect a solution for this? A separate script run manually or to be coupled with some other script?

Comment: Anything that works - from a better way to access env variables in cronjobs on AWS, to some bash/perl/sed/regex magic.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU sed` you can do something like below,

```
sed -r 's/RDS_PASSWORD=([[:graph:]]+)/RDS_PASSWORD="\1"/' /usr/local/bin/envvars
PYTHONPATH="/opt/python/current/app/mydjangoapp:$PYTHONPATH"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mydjangoapp.settings
AWS_ACTIVE='true'
RDS_PORT='5432'
RDS_HOSTNAME=hostname.host.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
RDS_USERNAME=master
RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
RDS_PASSWORD="My&Password"
```

You can then add the `-i` flag to `sed` to in-place substitution. I have used the character class `[[:graph:]]` which is

```
‘[:graph:]’
Graphical characters: ‘[:alnum:]’ and ‘[:punct:]’.
```

The special characters as part of `[:punct:]` are

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

So the `sed` can handle the substitution if any of these above characters constitute the `RDS_PASSWORD` variable.

The syntax you can use, is

```
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output yaml | \
    sed -n '1!p' | sed -e 's/^\(.*\): /\1=/g' | \
    sed -r 's/RDS_PASSWORD=([[:graph:]]+)/RDS_PASSWORD="\1"/' > /usr/local/bin/envvars
```

Comment: Is there a way to pipe the output of /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output yaml | sed -n '1!p' | sed -e 's/^\(.*\): /\1=/g' > sed -r 's/RDS_PASSWORD=([[:graph:]]+)/RDS_PASSWORD="\1"/'  > /usr/local/bin/envvars